# Filter - How to implement

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need to implement multi-choice filter in my Django software.
I have my model (database):

models.py

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    naziv = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naziv)      

class Clanak(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)   

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naslov) + ', ' + str(self.datumObjave) + ', ' + str(self.autor)
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('filtar/',views.filtar, name='filtar'),
]
```

Views.py:

```
def filtar(request):
    form = ChoiceForm(request.GET or None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all()    
    if form.is_valid():
        if 'Choice 1' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(naslov='name')
        if 'Choice 2' in form.cleaned_data['year']:
            data = data.filter(datumObjave__year='year')
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

Filtar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

        <tr>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        </tr>
        {% for x in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.naslov}}</td>
        <td>{{x.datumObjave}}</td>
        <td>{{x.autor}}</td>
    </tr>   
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body> 
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

footer.html

```
<br>
    <div>Filter: </div>
    <form>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Filtar - Thing that is being chosen</legend>

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div>Copyright by </div>
```

Forms.py

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    filter = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('Choice 1', 'Choice 1'), ('Choice 2', 'Choice 2')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    name = forms.CharField(label='name')
    year = forms.CharField(label='year')
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Now my question is:

My problem is that whatever I write in textfields it do nothing, just refresh page with all same data.
Name of dynamically created textboxes should be "nameinput" and "yearinput"

Comment: If you can pick both filters, why did you made them `radio` buttons instead of `checkbox`?

Comment: I switched it to checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is going to send `GET` request to the same page. So when view start processing, it fetch both choice values (if they exists), get all `Clanak` objects and filter them based on selected choices.
This way if no filters selected, you will get all objects. If both filters selected, it will filter both on names and year.

```py
def filtar(request):
    choice1 = request.GET.get('Autor', None)
    choice2 = request.GET.get('Datum', None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all()
    if choice1:
        data = data.filter(naslov='NAME')
    if choice2:
        data = data.filter(datumObjave__year=2019)
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data})
```

Note that it will not actually execute query before you try to access it (i.e. not until you render html).

Additionally, I would suggest you switch this form to django form, like this:

forms.py:

```py
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    filter = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('Choice 1', 'Choice 1'), ('Choice 2', 'Choice 2')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

views.py:

```py
def filtar(request):
    form = ChoiceForm(request.GET or None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all()    
    if form.is_valid():
        if 'Choice 1' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(naslov='NAME')
        if 'Choice 2' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(datumObjave__year=2019)
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

footer.html:

```
<br>
    <div>Filter: </div>
    <form>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Filtar - Thing that is being chosen</legend>

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div>Copyright by </div>
```

Comment: First of all - Thank You. I edited everything as You wrote. I am getting error now when I am trying to access on http://127.0.0.1:8000/filtar/. Error is: "module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'ChoiceForm'". I added to my "views.py" both "from django import forms" and "from app_1.forms import Forma, ClanakForma, ChoiceForm"

Comment: @justStarting oh, that's because I added whole file instead of particular form. Try updated version from answer and add form like `from .forms import ChoiceForm`

Comment: Thank You! Everything works as it should, now I'll just add fields so I can send parameters instead of having fixed filters.

Comment: Oh, I thought you **wanted** fixed filters. Yeah, you can just change `ChoiceForm` to use `form.CharField` to get filter variables.

Comment: Would You please be able if You have time to check my update above, I was trying but just can't get it to work. I added textboxes when checkbox is selectet but now it just do nothing when I press submit button.

Comment: @justStarting your form handles only radio buttons - it doesn't handle text inputs. So when you do `form.cleaned_data['nameinput']` - it will return nothing, since `nameinput` is not in form. Add both `CharField` to form.

Comment: Thank You, I fixed code and get everything back like it was, now I added two charfields at forms, now I am still don't geting data from that fields, am I reading it wrong at "views.py"?